# Error with pastebin API: Bad API request, invalid api_paste_format

Tags: c#, pastebin

I am using [this API](http://pastebin.com/ZpARSMNv), and [this is my program](http://pastebin.com/V73Q6UdX).

Whenever I try to send a paste to pastebin I get an error on line 77 in the API:

```
return resp;
```

I'm not sure what I should do to enable the post to send successfully.

> A first chance exception of type 'PasteBin.PasteBinApiException' occurred in WinForms_Run.exe Additional information: Bad API request, invalid api_paste_format

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'PasteBin.PasteBinApiException' occurred in WinForms_Run.exe

Additional information: Bad API request, invalid api_paste_format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you're encountering is actually on the line *before* `return resp`.

You should put a breakpoint on line 75 of `PasteBinClient` and evaluate the contents of the `resp` variable.

Based on the [pastebin API documentation](http://pastebin.com/api#2), you should get a message telling you exactly what's wrong with your request:

```
Bad API request, invalid api_option
Bad API request, invalid api_dev_key
Bad API request, IP blocked
... etc
```

EDIT: User commented with exact issue: `invalid api_paste_format`.

In your program (line 31) you're passing in "None" as the format - have you tried "text", as suggested by the API docs?

Comment: Bad API request, invalid api_paste_format - I'm lost, new to this

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question please don't forget to hit the "Mark as answer" button (tick on the left). :)

Comment: I will, have to wait 2 minutes